# how to find anchor tag in a div and push it to an array using jquery

Tags: jquery, tags

how to find anchor tag in a div and push it to an array using jquery. i tried it but my result shows arry=[jquery(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5)] and if i tried to check the array length it shows only one but not 5. please help. Iam getting the anchor tag by $(el).find('a');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [`toArray`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) method for jQuery objects. These method wil convert the jQuery result to a normal array:

```
$(el).find('a').toArray();
```